# Amazon spot instances getting terminating even when bid is above asking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi my spot instances are getting terminated even when its above the asking price.  Here is an example. 
[image]

so here it shows the last 3 hrs.  I also have one for the entire month.  However, even when bidding at 2.00 dollars the instance is still getting terminated.  Does anyone know what is going on here? thanks! 
A.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is not necessarily showing the full resolution of the Spot Price changes. You can retrieve the full information via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
$ aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --region us-west-1 \
  --availability-zone us-west-1a --instance-types i3.4xlarge \
  --product-descriptions Linux/UNIX --start-time 2017-12-11T00:00:00Z

{
    "SpotPriceHistory": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-12T04:17:22.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.216100"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-12T03:23:15.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.216100"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-11T20:25:19.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.214300"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-11T20:16:23.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.212600"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-11T12:53:31.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.212600"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-11T10:17:04.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.212500"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-11T07:12:02.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.212500"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-11T02:36:23.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.211400"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-12-10T19:38:34.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a", 
            "InstanceType": "i3.4xlarge", 
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
            "SpotPrice": "0.209900"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this clearly does not explain why your instance was terminated when the bid was $2.00.

Answer (score 0):

I see this happening, as well.

If you review the spot market price history over the past month, you'll find that spot pricing suddenly became much less volatile near the end of November, 2017.

> Spot instance prices are set by Amazon EC2 and adjust gradually based on long-term trends in supply and demand for Spot instance capacity.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/

If you are familiar with the history of spot pricing, you know the spot market did not always "adjust gradually."  The spot market price no longer sends the clear signal that it formerly did about short term supply and demand.

I have a cc2.8xlarge spot instance that seems to be interrupted fairly predictably at noon and midnight UTC, though not every day -- but on most days, it does.  The history of the spot request shows insufficient capacity for a few minutes, then the instance will start back up about 14 minutes later.

It isn't clear what specifically triggers this, but you do not have to have a bid below market price in order to have a spot instance reclaimed.

In fact, this has always been true, but often unnoticed until the market price reached unreasonable heights as real-time demand outpaced supply, at which point all the winning bidders were paying a ridiculously high price.  Under the new scheme, it appears that your high bid still allows you to improve your statistical odds of maintaining the instance over time, by pushing up the market price over time, rather than by causing an immediate shift in the market as was the case previously.

We may getting bumped by scheduled reserved spot instance requests, which start at specific times of day on a cycle... and once those instances finish their work and terminate, capacity becomes available again, but the capacity change is no longer reflected in minute-by-minute price fluctuations.  The increased stability of the spot market prices necessarily masks the real-time supply and demand signals, which almost certainly would result in increased demand as the price seems consistently more reasonable.

Comment: thanks Michael; its so frustrating to get bumped when the history clearly shows that the price well below what our high bids are. For me its 2 dollars and the entire plot shows its below 35 cents, ugh.